# A confusion about jquery custom queue's dequeue

Tags: jquery, queue

First I have a factory function to change the background color,the function is pushing a custom queue:

```
var changeBack = function (delay, color) {
    $('div').queue('custom', function (next) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('div').css({
                'background-color': color
            })
        }, delay)   
    })    
}
```

Then I want change the background color several times,then `dequeue` the queue:

```
$(function () {
    changeBack(1000, "yellow");
    changeBack(1000, "black");
    changeBack(1000, "blue");
    changeBack(1000, "gray");
    var custom = $('div').queue('custom');
    $('div').dequeue('custom');
})
```

but the `div` is only turn to yellow backgroung color,it means only execute the first function?But I have push the other function into the queue,how can I execute the other function ? 
here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/uVjQ4/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to delay is not `setTimeout`, but [**`$.fn.delay`**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/): http://jsfiddle.net/uVjQ4/8/

```
var changeBack = function (delay, color) {
    var $div = $('div'); //<-- Cached selector, so that the selected element(s) 
                         // are same throughout the whole function.
    $div.delay(delay, 'custom').queue('custom', function (next) {
        ....
        next(); // Trigger next
    });
};

....
// Initialize 
    $('div').dequeue('custom');
```